# Checkout of Master in bitbucket and then committing changes in bitbucket

Tags: git, bitbucket, cpu-word

Working with the bitbucket and git for the first time. I have a word document. I have to checkout it, make changes into it and checkin the document. I searched internet but no benefit. The link indicates that it a Master. There is a Check out button.
When i press it, it gives me git fetch && git checkout master   and   check out in SourceTree.
Can anyone give me some link, especially a video or make me understand how to carryout this task?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, here is an answer. First you need to clone the bitbucket repository. This works via ssh or https. For ssh you must have deposited your ssh key with bitbucket.
Then you can check out the master branch and commit your changes.
Maybe this could help you:

[learn-git-with-bitbucket-cloud](https://www.atlassian.com/en/git/tutorials/learn-git-with-bitbucket-cloud)